# Guarantee run after evalAsync finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, race-condition

Fairly new to Javascript and Angular.

I've got two pieces of code running in separate callbacks, being called from third party libraries. (Kendo UI library callbacks)

Function A() kicks off a $scope.evalAsync

Function B() assumes data has been set by A() and behaves accordingly.

These two functions cannot really interact with each other. Different scopes.

The contents of function B() need to wait for A() to finish before they can run.

Is there a way to achieve this elegantly?
The only thing I can think of is adding another boolean to $rootScope and maybe pausing a function until it flips from false to true.

Can't use $q promises because, as mentioned, A and B are both callbacks run in different areas by a third party library without linked scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, but I'd probably go with promises. The two evals are linked by the `$rootScope`. You could do something like this:

1. Create a promise on the rootScope when the application starts up.
2. When function `A()` completes, resolve that promise.
3. Ensure that function `B()` waits for the promise to be resolved before executing.

This assumes that the two functions will only run once. If they need to run multiple time, then a more complex setup is necessary.